# Specify DNS for Chrome

Tags: dns

My work uses a locked down DNS to control web browsing.  I get around this by specifying the DNS as 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  However, when doing so, I can't connect to my work email server.  Is there a way to set just Chrome to utilize the Google public DNS and allow all other applications to use the default DNS?

Comment: Trying to get around your company IT policies could lead to losing your job ...

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that this was the alternative to having a bypass code to get to the websites I need to do my job.  I handle our social media, and those are blocked by default.  Thanks for your concern, though.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just the email server, why not put the entry for that into your HOSTS file?

To specifically answer the question, no, you cannot have a different DNS for Chrome unless you have a separate network connection just for chrome since the DNS is set at the connection level. Even then you would have to tell your system which domains to query on which connection/DNS. So much easier to do it the other way around.

Comment: still needs one more point - have 10, congrats ;-)